# How to update related tables in entity-framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a table named `Tour` and another table name `TourPlan`.
These tables are related like below;

```
Tour                            TourPlan
Id (PK,int,not null)            Id (PK, int, not null)
Title (nvarchar(100), null)     Title (nvarchar(100), null)
                                TourId (FK, int, not null)
```

The problem is to update `TourPlan` table with existing values.

This is my code for updating;

```
Tour tour = TourController.GetTourById(Int32.Parse("13"));
tour.TourPlan.Clear();
foreach (ListItem item in lbPlans.Items)
   {
     tour.TourPlan.Add(new TourPlan() { Title = item.Text });
   }
```

And this is my update method;

```
public static int UpdateTour(Tour tour)
{
   using (var context = new aisatourismEntities())
     {
        Tour tUpd = context.Tour.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == tour.Id);
          if (tUpd != null)
            {
                tUpd.Title = tour.Title;
                tUpd.TourPlan = tour.TourPlan;
            }
          return context.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

But it's not updating, it inserts plan twice.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to update the data of TourPlan instead of overwriting the instance:

```
public static int UpdateTour(Tour tour)
{
   using (var context = new aisatourismEntities())
     {
        Tour tUpd = context.Tour.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == tour.Id);
          if (tUpd != null)
            {
                tUpd.Title = tour.Title;
                tUpd.TourPlan.Id= tour.TourPlan.Id;
                tUpd.TourPlan.TourId= tour.TourPlan.TourId;
                tUpd.TourPlan.Title = tour.TourPlan.Title;
            }
          return context.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

This of course supposes that you already have an attached instance of TourPlan. If not, you need to attach it to the DbContext.

Comment: Tour has multiple TourPlan so there is 1 to n relationship between two tables.

Comment: so Tour.TourPlan is a collection? In that case you should loop over the collection and copy the values.

Comment: Yes. It'is collection. But if user deletes a plan and adds another plan in update, how would this be achieved?

Comment: You would need to synchronize it with the DbContext. To do this you need to attach it to the context. You can check this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is how your method for updating TourPlan should look like:

```
    public static void UpdateTour(Tour tour, TourPlan tourPlan)
    {
        using (var context = new aisatourismEntities())
        {
            context.Tours.Attach(tour);

            context.Entity(tourPlan).Property(plan => plan.Title).IsModified = true;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The second parameter of the method has to be already "prepared" `TourPlan`.